# Search Crawl error on a single page

Tags: 2013, search, managed-metadata, crawling, crawl

This is a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise environment.  The crawler refuses to crawl a single page correctly.  No other errors show up in the crawl log and every other page is crawled correctly. The error that I see is:

> The crawler could not communicate with the server. Check that the
>   server is available and that the firewall access is configured
>   correctly.

This page is a custom content type and contains Managed Metadata fields.  Any new pages created from this content type also fail to crawl, even if all Managed Metadata fields are left blank.  I can hit the page directly from the server.  I suspect that has something to do with it but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.  Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Page Layout had a reference to 16.0.0.0 that was causing search to blow up.  The site started out as an O365 site but was recently migrated to on-prem; this must have slipped through the cracks.  Honestly, I'm surprised the page loaded at all.